# Azure.DocumentDb The MAC signature found in the HTTP request is not the same as the computed signature

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a class for working with azure cosmosdb. My class looks like this:

```
public class DocumentService : IDocumentService
{ 
    private readonly DocumentClient _client;
    private readonly string _collectionName;
    private readonly string _databaseName;

    public DocumentService(IDocumentDbConfig settings)
    {
        var connectionPolicy = new ConnectionPolicy
        {
            ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
            ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp,
            RequestTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0),
            MaxConnectionLimit = 1000,
            RetryOptions = new RetryOptions
            {
                MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = 10,
                MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds = 60
            }
        };

        _databaseName = settings.DocumentDbDatabaseName;
        _collectionName = settings.DocumentDbProductsCollectionName;
        _client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(settings.DocumentDbEnpointUrl), settings.DocumentDbPrimaryKey, connectionPolicy);
    }

    public IList<JObject> List(string query = "SELECT * FROM c") => _client.CreateDocumentQuery<JObject>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_databaseName, _collectionName), query, new FeedOptions {EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true}).AsEnumerable().ToList();

    public async Task SaveAsync(IEnumerable<JObject> models)
    {
        foreach (var document in models) {
            var documentLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(_databaseName, _collectionName, document["id"].ToString());
            await _client.CreateDocumentAsync(documentLink, document);
        }
    }

    public async Task DeleteAsync(string documentName, string partitionKey)
    {
        var requestOptions = new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey) };
        var documentUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(_databaseName, _collectionName, documentName);
        await _client.DeleteDocumentAsync(documentUri, requestOptions);
    }

    public async Task DeleteMultipleAsync(string partitionKey)
    {
        var requestOptions = new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey) };
        var query = $"SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.categoryId = '{partitionKey}'";
        var response = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<JObject>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_databaseName, _collectionName), query, new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true }).AsDocumentQuery();
        while (response.HasMoreResults)
            foreach (Document document in await response.ExecuteNextAsync())
                await _client.DeleteDocumentAsync(document.SelfLink, requestOptions);
    }
}
```

When I invoke the **SaveAsync** method, I get an error when it reaches `await _client.CreateDocumentAsync(documentLink, document)`.

The error is:

> The MAC signature found in the HTTP request is not the same as the computed signature

As I am using **Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB** I don't think it should be throwing this error.

Can someone help?

Comment: 2 questions. Are you getting the same error with both an emulator and the real service? Can you true Gateway over HTTPS too and see if you get that error?

Comment: Hey, locally my API is running on HTTPS, are you suggesting that it has to be real SSL? As for the emulator, I didn't know there was one. Do you have a link?

Comment: I am talking about the CosmosDB. All I'm really asking is to change `ConnectionMode.Direct` to `ConnectionMode.Gateway` and `Protocol.Tcp` to `Protocol.Https` and tell me if that worked. Not a solution but will narrow down the issue.
Also sure, here is the emulator documentation page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator

Comment: hmm, if I change it to what you said, I get a new error: ResourceType Document is unexpected

Answer (score 2):

Turns out my save method was creating the wrong link. I was using:

```
var documentLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(_databaseName, _collectionName, document["id"].ToString());
```

When it should have been:

```
var collectionLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_databaseName, _collectionName);
```

So the entire method should looks like this:

```
public async Task SaveAsync(IEnumerable<JObject> models)
{
    foreach (var document in models)
    {
        var collectionLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_databaseName, _collectionName);
        await _client.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionLink, document);
    }
}
```

Comment: This also applies to updates to existing documents: The **`UpsertDocumentAsync`** method expects a `documentCollectionUri`, not a `documentUri`, even though you used the latter to _read_ the existing document in the first place: `await _client.UpsertDocumentAsync(collectionLink, document);`